# prettify works on Soup but not on Soup1=Soup.find_all

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
MyAlphaSoup = BeautifulSoup(website_to_crawl.text, 'html.parser')

MyAlphaSoup.prettify()

MyAlphaAlphaSoup = MyAlphaSoup.find_all("div", {"class": "lister-item featurefilm"})

MyAlphaAlphaSoup.prettify()
```

I am getting an error at the 4th line

```
raise AttributeError( AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'prettify'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Isn't soup.find_all merely reducing the soup to a smaller subset? so the type isn't changing?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKve0.png)

[Code Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JPzY.png)

Comment: As you can see by the error message, find_all returns a LIST of valid elements. For example, if MyAlphaSoup contains the entire DOM, MyAlphaAlphaSoup will contain a subset of valid elements in a `LIST`. You can prettify an element within the list, but you have to select one, and not the entire list. Try to print(MyAlphaAlphaSoup) to understand it better.

Comment: @Sri for the respective print of type's... I'm getting <'bs4.element.ResultSet'> for 2nd soup and <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'> for 1st soup...what is this type of class? i thought soup was a single element...and alphalpha a list of elements?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the function find_all returns a list. So, you should be able to do that if you specify the element of the list or loop through them:

```
my_alpha_soup = BeautifulSoup(website_to_crawl.text, 'html.parser')

my_alpha_soup.prettify()

list_of_elements = my_alpha_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "lister-item featurefilm"})

for element in list_of_elements:
    print(element.prettify())
```

Also, is a convention to only use initial capital letters for classes.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand!